# ASP.NET Entity FrameWork remove() + ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

There is a list of managers (in fact a history), where current is marked as property with `TillDate == null` and `IsIsCurrentManager = true`.

```
db.MyManagers.Remove(db.MyManagers
    .Where(e => e.ProjectId == projectId 
                && e.MyManagerId == Id).First());
var newCurrentManager = db.MyManagers
    .Where(e => e.ProjectId == projectId)
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.FromDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
newCurrentManager.TillDate = null;
newCurrentManager.IsCurrentManager = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that `Remove()` method will only mark entity as `deleted`, but, as far as i can see, it still will be added to the list. How can deleted 1 record and than build a list of managers without it, without using  `SaveChanges()` 2 times or hardcoding `MyManagerList[2]`

Comment: @DavidG He is right, i miss klicked. sry

Comment: @DavidG sorry, i it just looks like typo to me.

Comment: @teovankot I'm sure it was correct, but in that situation it's always better to ask first, just in case it's not.

Comment: What is the unique or primary key of `MyManager`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that Entity Framework is just an interface into your data store and all you are usually doing is building queries, queries that don't actually run until you materialise the results of a `select` (i.e. by enumerating through the results or calling something like `ToList()` or `Single()`) or, in the case of an update/delete operation, when you call `SaveChanges()`.

So while you can do something like checking that the entity is tracked in the context as a deleted item, you are probably much better off sending the results to the database by calling `SaveChanges()` twice.

The secondary benefit of that is that another query that doesn't use the same context object (e.g. another web request) will be able to see that the item has been deleted while the original query is trying to pull the list of managers.

Comment: You are right about `SaveChanges`, but the *secondary benefit* is debatable. Many people will argue that one should wrap multiple `SaveChanges` with explicit transtaction.

Comment: You're right, it's debatable, I was just putting it in there as a potential benefit. It entirely depends on the use case at the time. There are situations where you may not want other people to see the changes you've made yet, or like you say, have this in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the **Entity State** to exclude it from the second list.
I also have updated the linq request with some cleaning.

*Also there is no chek for null, your db query can return null and should be managed as such.*

```
        db.MyManagers.Remove(db.MyManagers
                       .FirstOrDefault(e => e.ProjectId == projectId 
                          && e.MyManagerId == Id));
        var newCurrentManager = db.MyManagers
                       .ToList()
                       .Where(e => e.ProjectId == projectId 
                        && db.Entry(e).State != EntityState.Deleted)//This will query the entity traker 
                       .OrderByDescending(i => i.FromDate)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
        newCurrentManager.TillDate = null;
        newCurrentManager.IsCurrentManager = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You can't include state conditions in EF query because it cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated the answer you can bypass it with .ToList() but it may not be suitable. In wich case, DavidG answer make more sense.